# Golang generic JSON marshalling

Tags: arrays, json, go, marshalling

I'm working on s small server-client project based on JSON communication. But i run into issues. I'm trying to create a response struct with a generic message body. This means I have an map with a key as string and a json raw message as value. In the end the message body should work for any type (strings, integers, arrays)

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

type ServerResponse struct {
    Code int                    `json:"code" bson:"code"`
    Type string                 `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Body map[string]json.RawMessage `json:"body" bson:"body"`
}

func NewServerResponse() *ServerResponse {
    return &ServerResponse{Body: make(map[string]json.RawMessage)}
}





func main(){
    serverResponse := NewServerResponse()
    serverResponse.Code = 100
    serverResponse.Type = "molly"

    serverResponse.Body["string"] = json.RawMessage("getIt")
    serverResponse.Body["integer"] = json.RawMessage{200}
    serverResponse.Body["array"] = json.RawMessage(`["a", "b", "c"]`)


    if d, err  := json.Marshal(&serverResponse); err != nil{
        fmt.Println("Error " + err.Error())
    }else{
        fmt.Println(string(d))
   }
}
```

But the output is as follow.

```
{
  "code":100,
  "type":"molly",
  "body":  {
            "array":"WyJhIiwgImIiLCAiYyJd",
            "integer":"yA==",
            "string":"Z2V0SXQ="
           }
}
```

It seems like the values are Base64 encoded and inside double quotes. Tihs should be the expected output

```
{
  "code":100,
  "type":"molly",
  "body":  {
            "array":["a", "b", "c"],
            "integer":200,
            "string":"getIt"
           }
}
```

Is this even possible? Or do I have to write a specific struct type for every response?

Comment: Well, `json.RawMessage` is exactly for what you want to do but you should really get your code straight: E.g. `getIt` is **not** valid JSON as it misses double quotes. Try json.RawMessage(`"getIt"`). And what do you think `json.RawMessage{200}` produces? Please read what json.RawMessage really is and then think what `json.RawMessage{200}` yields. Your code does not compile and if it would it would not produce the output you showed. Please fix your question.

Comment: Mh.. This seems a bit strange. In JetBrains Gogland IDE the code compiles ans run without any errors. Whereas the same code fails at the Go Playground. So can I  use a raw message only for objects? Not for a single key/value pair?

Comment: Of course you can use it for single values: `json.RawMessage([]byte("200"))` or `json.RawMessage([]byte("true"))`. Dead simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw message must be valid JSON.

Add quotes to the string to make it a valid JSON string.

```
serverResponse.Body["string"] = json.RawMessage("\"getIt\"")
```

JSON numbers are a sequence of decimal bytes. A number is not the value of a single byte as attempted in the question.

```
serverResponse.Body["integer"] = json.RawMessage("200")
```

This one works as you expected.

```
serverResponse.Body["array"] = json.RawMessage(`["a", "b", "c"]`)
```

The program in the question compiles and runs with errors. Examining those errors and fixing them leads to my suggestions above.

An alternative approach is to replace the use of `json.RawMessage` with `interface{}`:

```
type ServerResponse struct {
  Code int                    `json:"code" bson:"code"`
  Type string                 `json:"type" bson:"type"`
  Body map[string]interface{} `json:"body" bson:"body"`
}
```

Set the response body like this:

```
serverResponse.Body["string"] = "getIt"
serverResponse.Body["integer"] = 200
serverResponse.Body["array"] = []string{"a", "b", "c"}
```

You can use json.RawMessage values:

```
serverResponse.Body["array"] = json.RawMessage(`["a", "b", "c"]`)
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Dpux6WFdB_)